# How to upload the picture to AWS s3 bucket?

Tags: android, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

```
//getting access to the photo gallery
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null) {
        Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
        uploadImage.setImageURI(selectedImage);
    }
    Toast.makeText(this, "Test", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}


 //Toast.makeText(this, "Test", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
//Trying to upload image to the AWS S3bucket-
public void uploadImageToAWS(View v) {
//String sdcard = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM).getAbsolutePath() + "Camera/";
    Toast.makeText(this, "Test", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    File MY_FILE = new File("myPhoto.png");
    String YOUR_IDENTITY_POOL_ID ="POOL_ID";
    CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider credentialsProvider =
            new CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider(getApplicationContext(),
                    YOUR_IDENTITY_POOL_ID,
                    Regions.US_EAST_1);


    AmazonS3Client s3Client = new AmazonS3Client(credentialsProvider);
    s3Client.setRegion(Region.getRegion(Regions.US_EAST_1));

    TransferUtility transferUtility = new TransferUtility(s3Client,
            getApplicationContext());

    TransferObserver observer = transferUtility.upload(
            "apptestingbucket",           // The S3 bucket to upload to
            FILE_NAME,   // The key for the uploaded object
            MY_FILE);// The location of the file to
    observer.setTransferListener(new TransferListener() {

        @Override
        public void onStateChanged(int id, TransferState state) {
            if(state == TransferState.COMPLETED){
                Toast.makeText(Social.this, "transfer Succeded!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(int id, long bytesCurrent, long bytesTotal) {
            int percentage = (int) (bytesCurrent/bytesTotal * 100);
            Log.e("Status", "Percentage" + percentage);

        }

        @Override
        public void onError(int id, Exception ex) {
            Log.e("MY_BUCKET", "Error: " + ex.getMessage() );

        }
    });




        }



private void retrieveImageFromAWS(){
    File sdcard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    File MY_FILE = new File(sdcard, "social.png");
    String YOUR_IDENTITY_POOL_ID ="POOL_ID";
    CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider credentialsProvider = new CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider(getApplicationContext(),
            YOUR_IDENTITY_POOL_ID
            , Regions.US_EAST_1);
    AmazonS3Client s3Client = new AmazonS3Client(credentialsProvider);
    TransferUtility transferUtility = new TransferUtility(s3Client,
            getApplicationContext());
    TransferObserver observer = transferUtility.download("BUCKET_NAME",
            "FILENAME_TO_BE_DOWNLOADED", MY_FILE);

    observer.setTransferListener(new TransferListener() {
        @Override
        public void onStateChanged(int id, TransferState state) {
            if(state == TransferState.COMPLETED){
                Toast.makeText(Social.this, "Retrieve completed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(int id, long bytesCurrent, long bytesTotal) {
            int percentage = (int) (bytesCurrent/bytesTotal * 100);
            Log.e("status", "percentage" +percentage);

        }

        @Override
        public void onError(int id, Exception ex) {
            Log.e("MY_BUCKET", "Error Downloading: " + ex.getMessage());


        }
    });


}
```

This is what i have based on the Android s3 documentation, I'm trying to pick the picture from photo gallery or take picture from the phone and upload it to S3 bucket and retrieve it back to the app interface. but evry time i run the programm my app crashed. and i called

```
  uploadImageToAWS(v)
```

insede the

```
 BtnUpload.onClicklistener
```

any example or little help would be appreciated. thank you!

Comment: 1) If the program is crashing, add the logcat 2) You probably need an AsyncTask to do any network operation

Answer (score 0):

Try to check if you have the uses-permissions Internet in your Android Manifests file. If this is not working, try to see if you can upload images outside your app (eg. via command line) to your bucket. Maybe there is some sort of security setting you have not set properly. Make sure you can ping your server and set up your security settings properly.